# Filling out paypal express checkout selenium

Tags: jquery, python, selenium, paypal, express-checkout

I'm new to SOF.
I have problem with filling out paypal login form.

I want my script to login into paypal express checkout page then click on pay button return to merchant site and click submit button.

for now I have this I've already tried several methods but I can't get it working.
It clicks paypal checkout button on merchant site then going to paypal but it does not fill anything and then script(chrome?) crashes and close chrome.

```
results=browser.execute_script("window.location='"+cartURL+"'")
checkBtn=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='co-actionscart-bottom- actions checkout-buttons-wrapper clearfix checkout-paypal']//button[@class='co-btn_primary btn_showcart button-full-width button-ctn button-brd-sol button-brd    adi-gradient-lightgrey paypal-button track btn btn-paypal btn-block']")
print(checkBtn)
checkBtn.click()
time.sleep(sleeping)
time.sleep(sleeping)
time.sleep(sleeping)
browser.switchTo().frame("injectedUl")
inputelement = browser.find_element_by_name("login_email")
inputelement.clear()
inputelement.send_keys(cardNum)
inputelement = browser.find_element_by_name("login_password")
inputelement.clear()
inputelement.send_keys(safeCode)`
```

Comment: This is a really bad idea security wise... other than that your locators are really bad and prone for errors. If you still want to solve it, you'll need to figure out if Chrome crashes or your script is throwing an exception.

Comment: How can i do this? in terminal nothing showing

Comment: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="724dfc1695588615266021576c0a8a37", element="0.7849961028040704-1")>

Comment: @Moshisho Can you pm me?

Comment: No PMs on SO, do you have an example URL?

Comment: For example add this product to cart               http://store.nike.com/gb/en_gb/pd/air-max-2017-running-shoe/pid-11156954/pgid-11610605                                                                           Then click checkout with paypal button and it will open Paypal express checkout page and this is the page I'm trying to fill

Comment: @Moshisho I have managed to do the fillout and click submit in this script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40577383/run-selenium-script-through-proxy-python-chrome

Comment: I don't understand, so you fixed your problem?

Answer (score 0):

**After** you switched to the iframe `"injectedUl"`, you have a `#shadow-root` under it which is sort of a hack of [JavaScript devs to encapsulate their implementation](https://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/). to get an element inside their you'll need something like:

```
htmlElement = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')

def expand_shadow_element(element):
shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
return shadow_root

shadow_root_under_frame = expand_shadow_element(htmlElement)
```

Then you can find the inputs your looking for:

```
inputelement = shadow_root_under_frame.find_element_by_name("login_email")
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```html
  if debug:
    print(d_()+z_("Debug")+o_("Product Count"+" : "+productCount))
  if (len(productCount) == 1) and (int(productCount) > 0):
    results=browser.execute_script("window.location='"+cartURL+"'")
    checkBtn=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='co-actions cart-bottom-actions checkout-buttons-wrapper clearfix checkout-paypal']//button[@class='co-btn_primary btn_showcart button-full-width button-ctn button-brd-sol button-brd adi-gradient-lightgrey paypal-button track btn btn-paypal btn-block']")
    print(checkBtn)
    checkBtn.click()
    htmlElement = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')

    def expand_shadow_element(element):
      shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)

    return shadow_root

    shadow_root_under_frame = expand_shadow_element(htmlElement)
    inputelement = shadow_root_under_frame.find_element_by_name("login_email")
    inputelement.clear()
    inputelement.send_keys(cardNum)
    inputelement=browser.find_element_by_name("login_password")
    inputelement.clear()
    inputelement.send_keys(safeCode)
```

Comment: It closes immediately browser